# Cоздать и инициализировать?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте нужно выполнить задания, прохожу курс. Создал класс с атрибутами. 
Создать и инициализировать псевдослучайными значениями
одномерный массив из 100 экземпляров класса.

```
class Clothes:
    material = "qwerty"
    price = "300"
    color = "red"
    country = "USA"
    def makeNoise(self):
        print("Страна "+self.country)
    made = Clothes()
    made.makeNoise()
```

Comment: import random,создайте конструктор def __init__(), который будет принимать несколько аргументов, запустите цикл, и инициализируйте Clothes(random.randint(1,100))

Comment: пожалуйста киньте кодом мне. буду благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
class Clothes:
    def __init__(self,randNum):
        self.randNum=randNum
    def printNum(self):
        print(self.randNum)
lstClass=[]
for i in range(1,101):
    lstClass.append(Clothes(random.randint(1,100)))

for i in range(len(lstClass)):
    a=lstClass[i]
    a.printNum()
```

В этой строке `material_lst[rd.randint(0,len(material_lst)-1)]` я получаю псевдослучайное целое число от 0 до длинны списка - 1, тк нумерация в Python с 0, и обращаюсь к элементу списка по индексу который равен этому случайному числу

```
import random as rd
class Clothes:
    def __init__(self,material,price,color,country,sale,size):
        self.material = material
        self.price = price
        self.color = color
        self.country = country
        self.sale = sale
        self.size = size
    def view_all(self):
        print(self.material)
lstClass=[]
material_lst=["Кожа","Шелк","Хлопок","Лен"]
color_lst=["Red","Green","Blue","Dark"]
country_lst=["Russia","Ukraine","USA","Portugal"]
for i in range(1,101):
    lstClass.append(Clothes(material_lst[rd.randint(0,len(material_lst)-1)],
    rd.randint(0,10000),
    color_lst[rd.randint(0,len(color_lst)-1)],
    country_lst[rd.randint(0,len(country_lst)-1)],
    rd.randint(0,100),
    rd.randint(0,60)))

for i in range(len(lstClass)):
    a=lstClass[i]
    a.view_all()
```

Comment: можно по примеру моего класа, а то он пропал, а то мне нужно его потом использовать

Comment: Поправил, почитайте немного про классы https://python-scripts.com/python-class

Comment: я не могу кинуть этот код в конец почему ошыбка? name = "Charlie"
    noise = "Woof!"
    color = "red"
    country = "USA"
    def makeNoise(self):
        print(self.name + " says: " )
    dog = Clothes()
    dog.makeNoise()

Comment: прикрепите Ваш полный код

Comment: вот, но мне нужно именно 100 экземпляров класса import random

class Clothes:
    material = "Кожа"
    price = "300"
    color = "red"
    country = "USA"
    sale = "30%"
    siZe = "43"
    
    def makeNoise(self):
        print("Страна "+self.country)
        print("Цена "+self.price)
        
made = [Clothes() for _ in range(5)]
for i in made:
    i.makeNoise()

Comment: в Вашем классе нет конструктора, он не может принимать значения при создании, сделайте конструктор как в моём примере добавьте туда Ваши поля, и запускайте цикл

Comment: он должен писать рандомные значения переменных, а не числа. Можете так сделать?

Comment: сделайте список, в него добавьте переменные, и с помощью рандомного индекса обращайтесь к элементу

Comment: Поправил код, можете проверить

Comment: Если у вас больше нет вопросов, то нажмите на галочку принятия ответа :)

Comment: можно мне материал =, цвет = и так далее У нас в программе ошыбка показует только материал(

Comment: просто измените поля под себя, макет у Вас есть